# redirect to setting to turn on location service in ios 7

Tags: ios7, location, application-settings

I want to redirect the user to the location services screen in setting from app in ios 7. i tried using this code

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];`

but it dint work.

Answer (score 1):

This method will **not work for devices running iOS 5.1 and greater**.

Comment: Can u please suggest the code which works on devices running iOS 5.1 and greater.